# Character Encoding - Find broken character?

Tags: php, character-encoding

Simple problem.. I need to detect this character �. If it exists I need to `utf8_encode` the string. strpos doesn't find it.. Server doesn't have `mb_detect_encoding`. Any ideas?

Some strings are valid so I can't utf8 encode a valid utf8 string or bad things happen..

Comment: Can you add some more context pls?

Comment: mb_strpos ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php

Comment: What do you mean by "broken" character? Do you mean the replacement glyph (U+FFFD) per se, or other character that was replaced by the replacement glyph? Maybe consult http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html and make your question more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all of the below are set to UTF-8:

1. Your database table/fields are set to store UTF-8.
2. Your MySQL (or other database) connection is transmitting in UTF-8.
3. Your definitive output is set to be UTF-8.